# Outlook Email, Calendar, and People not syncing

Tags: windows-10-mobile, email, calendars, outlook, people

I have a Microsoft account using (myEmail).outlook.com.

I get this error message:

> Something went wrong
>
> we're having a problem connecting to m.hotmail.com. Contact a support person or your service provider.
>
> Error code: 0x86000c09

I added a Gmail account to the mail app and it works fine. I can also access my myEmail.outlook.com email etc. on outlook.live.com . So it seems that both the app and the email are fine. It's just that the app won't connect to outlook.

I already removed my phone from my devices on the outlook account as suggested [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-outlook_mail/win-10-mail-app-sync-error-0x86000c09/b42bd7a7-44f4-4935-a239-7e92e8ebbed1). It did not help.

I have more than one phone on that account, and they are all acting the same way.

I have already detached these apps from the account and then reattached. All that that accomplished was to remove all contacts, calendar dates, etc. from the phone. :(

I have now reset a phone. Didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sorted itself out. Perhaps it was a problem with the servers.